# How do I implement SELU in TensorFlow.jl?

Tags: tensorflow, julia

I would like to use the SELU unit with the julia TensorFlow library.

How do I do it?

It is in the [python library](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/selu).
Before then there was code for it in [python by Günter](https://github.com/bioinf-jku/SNNs/blob/master/SelfNormalizingNetworks_MLP_MNIST.ipynb]

```
def selu(x):
    with ops.name_scope('elu') as scope:
        alpha = 1.6732632423543772848170429916717
        scale = 1.0507009873554804934193349852946
        return scale*tf.where(x>=0.0, x, alpha*tf.nn.elu(x))
```

`where` doesn't seen to work right in TensorFlow.jl

Comment: Crossref: https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/335

Comment: Nice and useful

Answer (score 2):

It is simply:

```
selu(x) = 1.0507select(x.<0, 1.76326exp(x) .- 1.0 , x)
```

`where` is not currently exported by TensorFlow.jl, though it can be found nonexported as `TensorFlow.Ops.where`.

I personally kinda dislike it, and prefer to use `find` or `select`  depending on if I want indexes, or if I want to chose the output. (To me, they are unrelated operations. And not worthy of multiple dispatch on the name `where`)
In this case we want the later so use `select`

You can fancy the function up a bit if you want to give the resulting node a name.
But that is all there really is do it.

#### Example of use:

```
julia> using TensorFlow

julia> sess=Session()
Session(Ptr{Void} @0x00007fa626702170)

julia> selu(x) = 1.0507select(x.<0, 1.76326exp(x) .- 1.0 , x)
selu (generic function with 1 method)


julia> run(sess, selu(constant(1.0)))
1.0507

julia> run(sess, selu(constant(0.0)))
0.0

julia> run(sess, selu(constant(-1000.0)))
-1.0507

julia> run(sess, selu(constant(1000.0)))
1050.7
```